# Parameters in functions (jquery/dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the same function for multiple links.
Here's my code.

```
<a class="col-md-4 nieuws-item btn" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="showDialog(dialog1); return false;" type="black">
    <p>sometext</p>
</a>

<a class="col-md-4 nieuws-item btn" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="showDialog(dialog2); return false;" type="black">
    <p>sometext</p>
</a>
```

-

```
function showDialog(dialogname)
{
    $("#" + dialogname).dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
}
```

-

```
<div id="dialog1" title="SIM Beurs 2015" style="display: none;">
    <p>test</p>
</div>


<div id="dialog2" title="SIM Beurs 2015" style="display: none;">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Am I looking in the right direction? If so, where is my mistake?

Comment: Where is your `dialog1` and `dialog2` defined?

Comment: @suvroc I just added it when you asked. Noticed that I forgot to add it.

Comment: [This question is off-topic (#2) because it's a simple typographic error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @zzzzBov If I knew that I wouldn't ask the question. Think about that for a moment.

Comment: @Qbyte, that is unimportant. Questions on SO are meant to last and be helpful to others, not just individual users. Consider this: If I post a question asking what's wrong with my code and it happens to contain a typo, I obviously hadn't been able to see the typo on my own, but what value is that typo to anyone else? That is the situation you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does not occur (and would be more obvious) if you avoid inline `onclick=` handlers and just use jQuery handlers. That would also keep the code with the handler.

This has the advantage of allowing multiple handlers per item and does not avoid some of the other cool events features jQuery provides.

e.g.

```
<a class="col-md-4 nieuws-item btn" data-dialog="dialog1" href="javascript: void(0)" type="black">
    <p>sometext</p>
</a>

<a class="col-md-4 nieuws-item btn" data-dialog="dialog2" href="javascript: void(0)" type="black">
    <p>sometext</p>
</a>
```

and use a jQuery handler like this:

```
$('.nieuws-item.btn').click(function(){
    var dialogname = $(this).data('dialog');
    $("#" + dialogname).dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

or, if the elements are added dynamically, use a delegated handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nieuws-item.btn', function(){
    var dialogname = $(this).data('dialog');
    $("#" + dialogname).dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing some quotes:

```
onclick="showDialog('dialog1'); return false;"
                    ^here   ^and here
```

Same for `dialog2`.

Comment: Ugh, dumb mistake. This worked. Thank you. I will accept the answer when Stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: That's not being dump, that's working hard all night when your eyes bleed and you don't see those 8 pixels anymore :) That happens all the time! In Extreme Programming it is solved with Pair Programming (4 eyes are better than 2).

Comment: On a side note. Why do people downvote every question that I ask?

Comment: Please read the guidelines about asking questions on SO. The error you had was a simple typo, which does normally not get answers on SO. I +1 to compensate :)

Comment: @pid Thanks again for the response. This was not a typing mistake though. I was not directly aware that the quotes had to be there. After you told me I was like 'ahh right, why didn\'t I think of that' but it's not like I would've figured it out on my own. Which confuses me a bit as to why it gets downvoted. Anyway my problem is solved thanks to you and I appreciate it.